# How does one rename all of an object's keys within an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mapping, reduce

Is there a way to change the key names in an array of object?

**Code:**
List of value to change the key name.

```
var keys = {
    id:'identifier',
    facility:'site',
    status:'info',
    date:'days'
};
```

Array of object to change the key names

```
var arrayObj = [{
    id:'jr210',
    facility:'earth',
    status:'sample info',
    date:'Feb 29, 2020'
},
{
    id:'tl980',
    facility:'mars',
    status:'sample info',
    date:'Jan 15, 2020'
}]
```

**Expected output:**

```
var newArrayObj = [{
        identifier:'jr210',
        site:'earth',
        info:'sample info',
        days:'Feb 29, 2020'
    },
    {
        identifier:'tl980',
        site:'mars',
        info:'sample info',
        days:'Jan 15, 2020'
    }]
```

Comment: Could the OP please more elaborate on why this Q. is tagged as `typescript`. The provided code uses good old JavaScript Syntax with `var` statements.

Comment: Hello @PeterSeliger, sorry for the late reply. I haven't check my account due to a busy schedule this week. I'll make sure to take note of what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `Object.entries` for the operation.

1. `reduce` is to re-group the property in the object
2. `Object.entries` is to retrieve the key and value pairs in the object.

```
type KeyForFinalResult = 'identifier'|'site'|'info'| 'days'
type KeyForReferenceKeys = 'id' | 'facility' | 'status' | 'date' 

type TempObjectType = {
    [T in KeyForReferenceKeys | string ]: string
}

type FinalObjectType = {
    [T in KeyForFinalResult | string]: string
}

var keys: TempObjectType  = {
    id:'identifier',
    facility:'site',
    status:'info',
    date:'days'
};


var arrayObj:TempObjectType[] = [{
    id:'jr210',
    facility:'earth',
    status:'sample info',
    date:'Feb 29, 2020'
},
{
    id:'tl980',
    facility:'mars',
    status:'sample info',
    date:'Jan 15, 2020'
}]


const result = arrayObj.reduce((finalResult: FinalObjectType[], elem)=>{
    let temp: FinalObjectType = {} as FinalObjectType

    Object.entries(keys).forEach((entry: string[] )=> {
        //each entry: [[key, value],[key1, value1]...]
        temp[entry[1]] = elem[entry[0]]
    })
    
    finalResult.push(temp)
 
    return finalResult
},[])


console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the temp[entry[1]] "Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: @thePeculiarCoder Check my updated answer. The reason of the error is because of the type is not yet specified and typescript cannot infer. Once the type is added. Problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task. Like almost every array method [`map` allows a 2nd argument, the `thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail), a context which gets bound to the callback method and thus is accessibly at such a method's apply/call time.

The provided approach implements a callback method `remapObjectWithBoundKeys` which utilizes its this context as configuration of how to remap each of an object's key. It does so by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works)ing the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of its key-config and creating a new object by iteratively [`assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)ing new key-value pairs to it.

```js
const sampleList = [{
  id:'jr210',
  facility:'earth',
  status:'sample info',
  date:'Feb 29, 2020',
}, {
  id:'tl980',
  facility:'mars',
  status:'sample info',
  date:'Jan 15, 2020',
}];

function remapObjectWithBoundKeys(item) {
  const keyConfig = this;
  return Object
    .entries(keyConfig)
    .reduce((obj, [recentKey, currentKey]) => Object.assign(obj, {
      [currentKey]: item[recentKey]
    }), {});
}

console.log(
  sampleList.map(remapObjectWithBoundKeys, {
    id: 'identifier',
    facility: 'site',
    status: 'info',
    date: 'days',
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The advantage of the implemented method is that it operates independently from a `map` task. One easily can utilize or re-use it for any kind of object (re)creation ...

```js
function remapObjectWithBoundKeys(item) {
  const keyConfig = this;
  return Object
    .entries(keyConfig)
    .reduce((obj, [recentKey, currentKey]) => Object.assign(obj, {
      [currentKey]: item[recentKey]
    }), {});
}

const planetType = {
  id:'tl980',
  facility:'mars',
  status:'sample info',
  date:'Jan 15, 2020',
};
const recreatePlanetItem = remapObjectWithBoundKeys.bind({
  id: 'identifier',
  facility: 'site',
  status: 'info',
  date: 'days',
});

console.log(
  planetType,
  recreatePlanetItem(planetType)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @thePeculiarCoder ... are there any questions regarding the above approach?